# Sleeping in Yosemite park

Tags: sleeping, campers, yosemite

I was thinking of renting a camper van and wondered if it's safe to sleep in the van. Are there designated areas where one can park and stay overnight in a van?

Comment: What do you mean by safe?

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, this is [not permitted](https://www.nps.gov/yose/planyourvisit/nrcamping.htm):

> Within Yosemite National Park, you may not sleep in your car or RV except in a campsite that you're registered to stay in (except at Camp 4, where sleeping in cars is not allowed because it's a walk-in campground). Sleeping in your car along the side of the road is also not allowed.

You'd need to sleep at a campsite or outside the park. See the guide to [Visiting Yosemite With an RV](https://www.nps.gov/yose/planyourvisit/rv.htm), including [this map](https://www.nps.gov/yose/planyourvisit/upload/rideyarts.pdf) showing free and paid locations around the park with RV parking.

Comment: So actually, it **is** permitted. You just, y’know, *need a permit*. (And to be in one of the designated campsites. Which is typical.)